# Android 4.4 default button restoration?

Tags: launcher, buttons, user-interface

Android 4.4 comes with an app button in the bottom panel. If it gets deleted, how do I get it back?

Comment: Are you talking about the dock? Do you have a 3rd-party Launcher app installed? Also, it would help if you listed the Android OS version you are using.

Comment: I'm running Kit Kat/ CM11.

Comment: Assuming it's the default launcher, you should be able to drag and drop app shortcuts from the app drawer onto the dock, just like you would when placing them on the home screen.

Comment: @geffchang does the answer in that question still apply to CM11?

Comment: @Chahk I would assume Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the [Google Now Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher) this is supposedly not deletable. Other launchers allow customization and offer the button as a shortcut to a "launcher action". If you long press on an empty region on your home screen it should ask you whether you want to place a launcher action there. If you just go thru the options in that list it should be quite easy to find.

Here's are some screenshots for [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) on my i9100 running 4.4.2.

[image: Finding Widgets Menu]

[image: Launcher Actions]

[image: Added Icon]